# Rolling ball game, when i use S(backward) ball fly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a game in unity using c#. In this game I have a rolling ball. I wanted to rotate the camera with the mouse and WASD keys.

That means when I use W it should go forward, but if I had rotated my camera, the forward direction should change as well (so the camera is always behind the ball)
I have made a script that does the job, but there is a problem;
when I use the S key to go back, the ball starts flying backward! How can I solve this problem?

I think this happens because of the angle of camera that is looking at the ball.
Additionally, when I go forward, the speed is a little slow, so I think the angle of camera has some effect on moving. Maybe I should just remove the *angle effect*?

This is my script:

Player Control Script

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class playercontroller2 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float speed;
     private Rigidbody rb;
     void Start()
     {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

     }
     // Use this for initialization
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

         Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        movement = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(movement);// this make ball goes in right direction ( W will be the place that  camera looking )
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
     }
 }
```

Camera script

```
public float turnSpeed = 4.0f;
public Transform player;

private Vector3 offset;

public float zoomStep = 30f;
public float zoomSpeed = 5f;
private float heightWanted;
private float distanceWanted;

private Vector3 zoomResult;
private Quaternion rotationResult;
private Vector3 targetAdjustedPosition;
public float height = 20f;
public float distance = 20f;
public float min = 10f;
public float max = 60;


void Start () {
   // _offset = new Vector3(0, 22, 33);
  offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
  offset = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y + 8.0f, player.position.z + 7.0f);

}


// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
    transform.position = player.position + offset;
    transform.LookAt(player.position);


}
void Update()
{

        float mouseInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        heightWanted -= zoomStep * mouseInput;
        distanceWanted -= zoomStep * mouseInput;

        // Make sure they meet our min/max values.
        heightWanted = Mathf.Clamp(heightWanted, min, max);
        distanceWanted = Mathf.Clamp(distanceWanted, min, max);

        height = Mathf.Lerp(height, heightWanted, Time.deltaTime * zoomSpeed);
        distance = Mathf.Lerp(distance, distanceWanted, Time.deltaTime * zoomSpeed);

        // Post our result.
        zoomResult = new Vector3(0f, height, -distance);

   }
}
```

So to be clear, when I use this script, when I press back ( S or down arrow ), the ball starts to fly backward but I don't have this problem with other directions.

Comment: Only have time for a comment. Camera.main.transform will cause W to add a force directly away from the camera and S to add a force tword the camera. I bet if you put the camera underground W will break and S will work fine.

Comment: yeah it may be ok if  i put camera in ground, but i want camera always look from upside to ball  ( like 45 degree looking,that many 3rd person games using )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the force vectors you are applying are all in line with with the camera axis instead of the world axis.

What you need to do is change the rotation around the Y axis only but leave all other parts of the direction alone. This can be done using `Quaternion.LookRotation` to fix the rotation.

I don't have unity in front of me to test but I think this will do what you need.

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
Transform temp = Camera.main.transform;

//Fix the rotation to be flat with the Up vector.
temp.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward)

//Apply the transform to the movement
movement = temp.TransformDirection(movement);

rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

EDIT: Here is a updated simpler version that may work better, this just grabs the rotation of the camera around the y axis and then transforms your movement vector by the same amount.

```
void FixedUpdate()
 {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical) 

    //Fix the rotation to match the direction of the camera's y axis.
    Vector3 fixedMovement = Quaternion.Euler(0, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * movement;

    rb.AddForce(fixedMovement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: it didnt work as well, it was like before when i added ur code , but i changed  one line to this,  and it reversed the action, when i use W it fly toward .temp.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.up)    . by the way the problem still stand :(

Comment: @behzad see my update, there is a much simpler solution that should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you transform your `Vector3` ?

just comment this line in *Player Control Script*:

```
movement = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(movement);
```

Comment: this cod do the main job, if u remove this ball always go to one direction, i want to ball move to forward of camera ( every place camera looking, ball go to that way with W )